# How can I find out what was replaced in a Perl substitution?

Tags: regex, perl

Is there any way to find out what was substituted for (the "old" text) after applying the `s///` operator?  I tried doing:

```
if (s/(\w+)/new/) {
    my $oldTxt = $1;
    # ...
}
```

But that doesn't work. `$1` is undefined.

Comment: As always, show us a complete, minimal program with offending inputs that demonstrate the problem. The error could be somewhere else.

Comment: It must be somewhere else, because the code he's posted works just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Your code works for me.  Copied and pasted from a real terminal window:

```
$ perl -le '$_ = "*X*"; if (s/(\w+)/new/) { print $1 }'
X
```

Your problem must be something else.

Comment: maybe his expression did not match, then no substitution occur and $1 is not set.

Comment: if it did not match then it would not even get into the body of the "if"

Comment: @JoelFan: My guess is that you simplified the code in order to post it here, and in doing so removed whatever the bug was.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using 5.10 or later, you don't have to use the potentially-perfomance-killing `$&`. The `${^MATCH}` variable from the `/p` flag does the same thing but only for the specified regex:

```
 use 5.010;

 if( s/abc(\w+)123/new/p ) {
      say "I replaced ${^MATCH}"
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

`$&` does what you want but see the health warning in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> The use of this variable anywhere in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty on all regular expression matches.

If you can find a way to do this without using `$&`, try that. You could run the regex twice:

```
my ($match) = /(\w+)/;
if (s/(\w+)/new/) {
    my $oldTxt = $match;
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the replacement an [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) expression:

```
if (s/(\w+)/$var=$1; "new"/e) { .. do something with $var .. }
```

Comment: While this would work, there's no need for it.  The code he posted is correct as-is.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the Perl match variables:

> `$&`   Contains the string matched by the last pattern match